# Export d3 word cloud as png with button

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, export, word-cloud

I am trying to export a word cloud to png using a button.

More specifically, I try to merge [Rokotyan's implementation](http://bl.ocks.org/Rokotyan/0556f8facbaf344507cdc45dc3622177) for d3's circles with [ericcoopey's example](http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/6382449) of a wordcloud.

I put the code to steer the button inside the the `draw()` function:

```
function draw(words) {
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 850)
            .attr("height", 350)
            .attr("class", "wordcloud")
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(320,200)")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(words)
            .enter().append("text")
            .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });

     d3.select('#saveButton').on('click', function(){
       var svgString = getSVGString(svg.node());
       svgString2Image( svgString, 2*width, 2*height, 'png', save );

       function save( dataBlob, filesize ){
         saveAs( dataBlob, 'D3 vis exported to PNG.png' );
       }
     });
     // other functions come here
}
```

On clicking the button there is no download, also the object exists (when log `svgString` I get some output, but it's much shorter than `svgString` in ericcoopey's example).  What's wrong here?

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/merose/k7eL3k3y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check `svg.node()` in the console, it's just a subset of texts and so the `svgString` isn't the representation of the `SVG` in whole. And the error lies in the `var svg` declaration i.e. the variable `svg` is assigned a `g` and then `selectAll(text)` makes its value just to be a subset of texts.

If you change the declaration of `var svg` to the following structure:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 850)
  .attr("height", 350)
  .attr("class", "wordcloud");

svg  
  .append("g")
  // without the transform, words words would get cutoff to the left and top, they would
  // appear outside of the SVG area
  .attr("transform", "translate(320,200)")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(words)
  .enter().append("text")
```

If you now check the console for `svg`, it'll be the entire **SVG NODE** (which is what is required to be serialized to a string). Exporting this will result into a valid png.

Here's a demo:
[Export d3 word cloud to PNG](https://jsfiddle.net/k7eL3k3y/3/)

Hope this helps.